# Unable to click on a .png image link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Friends,

I'm struggling in opening specific tab of a Microstrategy dashboard where the name of dashboard is in form of image. Here is the HTML code of the header on which i need to click. M using selenium web driver in python.
Please suggest:-

```
<img src="./Images/DSI Images/NewWeb/Active_/Home.png" style="width:144px;height:48px;" onclick="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('*lK36*kK258*x1*t1526016913721','click', self, event)">
```

I tried following ways but not working:-

Scenario 1:-

In this scenario code is coming till `"print("wait over")"` but post that it fails

```
print("waiting...")
sleep(15)
print("wait over")
home_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='*lK36*kK258*x1*t1525928239926']/div")
home_element.click()
```

Scenario 2:-

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('*lK36*kK258*x1*t1525928239926').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].click()")
```

Scenario 3:-

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'DSI Images/NewWeb/Active_/Home')]").element_to_be_clickable)
```

Scenario 4:-

```
shared_reports_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//img[@src='./Images/DSI Images/NewWeb/Active_/Home.png']"))
shared_reports_button.click()
```

Scenario 5:-

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('./Images/DSI Images/NewWeb/Inactive_/Home.png').click()
```

Scenario 6:-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='./Images/DSI Images/NewWeb/Inactive_/Home.png')."])).click();
```

Scenario 7:-

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mstrmojo-DocImage hasLink']/img src[@class='./Images/DSI Images/NewWeb/Active_/Home.png']"))).click()
```

Comment: HTML code where you are trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared possibly the *AUT* is based on *JavaScript* and/or *AjaxCalls* so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and to invoke `click()` on the desired `<img>` you can use either of the following options :

- `CSS_SELECTOR` :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[href*=Images/NewWeb/Active_/Home.png]"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH` :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@href,'Images/NewWeb/Active_/Home.png')]"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH` (absolute attribute) :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@href=\"./Images/DSI Images/NewWeb/Active_/Home.png\"]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```